# javascript JSONP callback function not defined

Tags: javascript, jsonp

```
(
function restoreURL() {
    function turnLongURL(data) {
        window.location = data.url;
    }

    var shortUrl = window.location.href;

    var url = "http://json-longurl.appspot.com/?url=" + shortUrl + "&callback=turnLongURL";

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', url);

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); 
})();
```

code is above, but the **firebug** told me, turnLongURL is *not* defined

why is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSON-P is added to the document using a `script` element, so the function call inside it has to reference a function that exists in the global scope.

`turnLongURL` is limited to the scope of `restoreURL` since it is defined inside it.

Moving the function declaration to the global scope, or changing it to a function statement thus:

```
window.turnLongURL = function (data) {
```

… should make it work.

Remember to account for the possibility of race conditions should multiple JSON-P requests be sent out before the first returns.

Comment: it is still not working, and keep saying turnLongURL is not defined... 
does it make any difference if i am editing a greasemonkey script?

Comment: @Quentin What is the best way to account for jsonp race conditions?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495825/jsonp-request-in-chrome-extension-callback-function-doesnt-exist